# Has the UK spent millions of pounds to track a fugitive other than Assange?

Tags: united-kingdom, crime, rule-of-law

From an [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/28334/270) to "Why is the British government so determined to arrest Julian Assange?":

> And now someone can tell me why it is not unusual that a government pays millions of pounds to track a fugitive (give a counterexample, please)

Some people have been alleging that Assange has been singled out. Has the UK spent million of pounds tracking a fugitive or a group of fugitives other than Assange? Or is this something that's only happened to Assange?

Comment: You might want to rephrase to avoid the terrorist hunting. Sophisticated organized crime also might require long observations.

Comment: Does [terrorist hunting](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2011/05/the-cost-of-bin-laden-3-trillion-over-15-years/238517/) count?

Comment: Having given that specific answer: Assange was charged with sexual assault until 2017 und after this was revoked, is now charged with skipping bail. Current maximum sentence for skipping bail before a Magistrate Court is three months. So for a valid counterexample I would accept a common criminal who committed an offense punishable up to three months where the UK government spent equal or more than the equivalent of 10 million pounds today to track/get him.

Comment: @ThorstenS. but you could then argue than only the costs incurred after the sexual assault charges were dropped are relevant for the comparation (because before that the spending was done to get an -alleged- sexual agressor).

Comment: Notably, the money to hunt Assange has largely come out of the budget for guarding embassies, which they're arguably doing when they stand around waiting for Assange to stick his head out. *From a certain point of view*, they've not spent anything extra

Comment: This will be difficult to answer because the police services don't routinely compile costs of individual operations.

Assange is a unique case; I can't think of anyone else who sought asylum in an embassy after absconding from bail conditions they themselves suggested.

And it makes me wonder if people complaining about the cost have a specific threshold in mind - "for alleged crime X we'll give up if the cost of the investigation exceeds Y." If there were such a threshold I would understand if it weren't in the public domain.

Comment: Usually when someone skips bail, you don't know where they are - so after checking the abodes of friends and family (done by officers who would be going around checking things anyway) the only thing to do is wait for them to pop up using a credit card or something (on systems that would be monitoring things anyway).  Assange was unique in that he skipped bail and *everyone in the world* knew where he was. How could the police possibly *not* monitor the building they knew he was in? (Using officers who would be milling around monitoring that building and others anyway.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Has the UK spent millions of pounds to track a fugitive other than Assange?**

Lets remind ourselves of the timeline

- August 2010 - Assange visits Sweden, two women report rape. After being questioned, Assange leaves Sweden.
- 20 November 2010 - Interpol issue a red notice for Assange's arrest.
- December 2010 - Assange granted bail by a UK court.
- 19 June 2012 - Assange enters Ecuadorian Embassy.
- 12 October 2015 - [Metropolitan police cease monitoring of embassy](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/oct/12/julian-assange-police-removed-from-outside-ecuadorian-embassy).
- May 2017 - [Swedish prosecutors drop investigation of alleged rape](https://www.theguardian.com/media/2017/may/19/swedish-prosecutors-drop-julian-assange-investigation).

> A statement from the Metropolitan Police Service (MPS) on Monday said the operation to arrest Assange continued but it was “no longer proportionate to commit officers to a permanent presence”.

Note that, if my timeline is correct, the Met dropped the expensive 24 hour surveillance years before the Swedish police ceased investigating the rape allegations.

The major cost was incurred at a time when the alleged crime was rape, not when the alleged crime was breaking bail conditions and failing to attend court.

---

In order to formulate an answer to this or to understand any answer, you need to define a few things

- UK
- Fugitive

The legal entity making this expenditure is the Metropolitan police. It is entirely their choice how they allocate their budget to individual criminal investigations.

---

It is actually very rare for fugitives to be granted asylum and remain in London for three years. So it would be hard to find a directly equivalent prior case that matches Assange's in all respects

People alleged to have committed serious crimes such as rape are rarely fugitives in London for that many years *after an arrest warrant has been issued*. So there may be no exactly parallel cases whose costs can be compared.

However, it is not unusual for the Metropolitan police to fruitlessly spend millions of pounds investigating alleged crimes.

[Operation Midland](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-37027144)

> The Metropolitan Police has confirmed that one of its high-profile child sexual abuse investigations, Operation Midland, cost £2.5m in total.
>
> It includes staffing costs and overtime expenditure, Scotland Yard said.
>
> The figure comes after the Met said it would be unable to calculate the cost.
>
> The inquiry investigated historical claims of sex abuse and murder made against establishment figures. It closed in March without any charges being brought.

In this case the suspects were not fugitives, but if they had been, there is good reason to expect that more money would have been spent, not less.

---

UK police forces do often spend millions of pounds trying to track down the location of a single person in order to bring an investigation to a conclusion.

[The police investigation into missing RAF airman Corrie Mckeague has cost £2.1m to date](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-suffolk-42808142)

Of course, Corrie Mckeague is not a fugitive, just a missing person.

Comment: It's generally suspected that the rape allegations were fabricated for the purposes of getting him arrested. That's also one of the reasons news media rarely brings that aspect up anymore.

Comment: @forest: The admittedly fascinating subject of the soundness of allegations against Assange has absolutely no bearing whatsoever on the OP's question of whether or not the Met has a *prior history* of spending large sums on investigations.